# Problemas con jquery-treetable Expand y Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy cargando archivos mediante un input y pasando ese archivo a un treetable expandible, cuando cargo la primera vez la tabla se imprime correctamente, pero cuando selecciono un nuevo documento, se carga la tabla, pero ya no funciona el expandible.

De ante mano agradezco por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo destruyendo la instancia de treetable para que inicie una nueva al momento que cargo el nuevo documento

```html
   $("#id_tabla").treetable('destroy');
```